# Shovel Knight on 3DS returns error 005-6710 trying to update

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, shovel-knight

When I use the Update option on the Shovel Knight main menu, the progress bar advances three times, then returns the following error:

> ### Error Code: 005-6710
>
> An error has occurred.
> Please try again later.
>
> For help, visit [support.nintendo.com](http://support.nintendo.com/).

My Internet connection is working properly and my 3DS is correctly configured for WiFi internet access. I don't have any blocked ports on my end. [Nintendo support](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/wfc/en_na/ds/results.jsp?error_code=005-6710&system=3DS&locale=en_US) says this:

> An error occurred while attempting to connect to the Nintendo eShop.

However, the eShop doesn't seem to be down. A Google search turns up nothing regarding this error. Besides, if the game is already up-to-date, it shouldn't be returning a weird error message when trying to update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the publishers website, 1.1 is the current 3DS version:
http://yachtclubgames.com/update-notes/

I get the same thing trying to update on my system - and I have 1.1... I assume this is just a "no update available" situation that was not handled very well.